# Pandas drop duplicates with groupby and according to various conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(...)

a   b   c      d     e     f      
1  two  adc   aaaa   Nan   mmm    
2  one  Nan   aaa    Nan   nnn    
1  one  ab    Nan    Nan   ww     
1  two  abcd  aaa    ff    uiww  
1  two  a     aaa    d     iii
```

I want to drop duplicates according to 'a' and 'b'.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'])
```

1. But I want to leave in columns 'c', 'd' and 'e' value with max length.
2. And I want to leave in column 'f': 
   value that does not contain ('m' or 'n')
   or the value that contains ('w' or 'y').
   If the previous conditions are not met, then take any value.

I want to get this result:

```
a   b   c      d     e     f      
1  two  abcd  aaaa   ff    uiww   
2  one  Nan   aaa    Nan   nnn    
1  one  ab    Nan    Nan   ww
```

I tried to use `transform` and `apply`, but it was not possible to reduce to one scheme. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you possibly doing with this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your conditions create the function , then using `agg` with `groupby`

```
def yourfunc1(x):
    return x.loc[x.str.len().idxmax()]
def yourfunc2(x):
    if any(x.str.contains('w|y')|(~x.str.contains('m|n'))):
       return x.loc[x.str.contains('w|y')|(~x.str.contains('m|n'))].iloc[0]
    else :
        return x.iloc[0]
df=df.replace({'Nan':''})
s=df.groupby(['a','b'],as_index=False).agg({'c':yourfunc1,'d':yourfunc1,'e':yourfunc1,'f':yourfunc2})
   a    b     c     d   e     f
0  1  one    ab              ww
1  1  two  abcd  aaaa  ff  uiww
2  2  one         aaa       nnn
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to use groupby (which is slow with large data frames) you can do the following:

```py
def custom_drop_duplicates(dataframe):
    localDF = dataframe.copy()

    criteria_list = []
    for i, col in enumerate(['c', 'd', 'f']):
        localDF.loc[:, 'criteria{}'.format(i)] = [len(x) for x in localDF[col]]
        criteria_list.append('criteria{}'.format(i))

    localDF.loc[:, 'criteria{}'.format(i+1)] = [all(x not in y for x in ['m', 'n']) or any(x in y for x in ['w', 'y']) for y in localDF['f']]
    criteria_list.append('criteria{}'.format(i+1))

    # here you have a judgement call: if criteria are in conflict, you need to order them. I just assume they are ordered in the way you described them.

    localDF.sort_values(by=criteria_list, ascending=True, inplace=True)
    localDF.drop_duplicates(subset=['a', 'b'], keep='last', inplace=True)

    localDF.drop(columns=criteria_list, inplace=True)

    return localDF
```

Hope this helps